# github exclusions on live server

Tags: git, svn, netbeans, github

So I am using the tutorial here:

```
https://gist.github.com/oodavid/1809044
```

to deploy a gituhub project to our live server. Looks good and easy enough, but we have a set of files on our production server that we want excluded from any versioning, because they are special production versions of the same files we have in the repository, and will not be changed. We already have the files on the live server, so we don't need to initially commit them or anything. We just can't have them overwritten or deleted when we pull from the origin onto the server, and I could see how that would delete them if they didn't exist in the repo and/or there were like-named files(but development versions) in the repo. Someone else set it up this way on our server with SVN way back when, and now I have to do the same with git. I am open to other ways of handling it.

I know I need a file that with the exclusions... just not sure how to tell git about the exclusions file given the flow listed in the github tutorial.

Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify deployment script by replacing `git pull` with these commands:

1. `git commit -a -m "local changes"`, it's required because you cannot merge when you have some uncommited changes;
2. `git fetch`, it will fetch changes from remote;
3. `git merge FETCH_HEAD --ff -X ours -m "merge"`, it will merge changes from remote, using local versions of files when conflicts occur.

Finally, list of commands in deployment script will look like this:

```
$commands = array(
    'echo $PWD',
    'whoami',
    'git commit -a -m "local changes"',
    'git fetch',
    'git merge FETCH_HEAD --ff -X ours -m "merge"',
    'git status',
    'git submodule sync',
    'git submodule update',
    'git submodule status',
);
```